# how to find the distinct records in a CSV file using sql * loader

Tags: sql, loader

it is possible to find records

Answer (score 0):

SQL Loader is a utility that inserts data from data file(s) into database table(s). You can't find distinct records in the file using it.
If the table is defined with `primary` key(s), referential integrity and `check` constraints, those duplicate records from your `csv` file won't get inserted into the table. SQL loader will reject those records as `bad` records.